# Process result of Reducer before storing them

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am trying to write a HBase MapReduce Job which will produce the top10 users of my HBase table.

with the following Reducer,

```
class Top10usersReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, TreeMap<Text,IntWritable>  {

public static final byte[] CF = "infos".getBytes();
public static final byte[] COUNT = "count".getBytes();
static TreeMap<Text,IntWritable> map = new TreeMap<Text,IntWritable>();

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int sum = 0;

        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        map.put(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        context.write(null,map);

}
}
```

I had this output, each record is store in one line:

```
id11841=4,id11993=8,id12493=6,id12592=2,id12706=7,id12871=1,id12990=3,id13092=10,id13528=5,id13580=9
```

I would like to have this result:

```
id13092=10,id13580=9,id11993=8,id12706=7,id12493=6,id13528=5,id11841=4,id12990=3,id12592=2,id12871=1
```

Please, any idea on which process to add to the Reducer in order to achieve this goal?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289508/sorting-by-value-in-hadoop-from-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

The MR job which is performed sorts the output by key. So if you want to sort the output of reducer by values, you need to write another MR job.